# PicHandle to CGImageRef

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, cgimage, quickdraw

This project is a generic C++ plugin with core-graphics support. I am unable to convert a PicHandle to CGImageRef successfully. Saving off image from CFDataRef results in a bad image.

```
    if(pic)
{
    Handle thePictureFileHandle;
    thePictureFileHandle = NewHandleClear(512); 
    HandAndHand((Handle)pic,thePictureFileHandle);

    dataProvider= CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,(void*)*thePictureFileHandle,GetHandleSize( (Handle)thePictureFileHandle ),NULL );
    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL);
    if ( source )
    {
        cgImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
    }
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CFRelease( source );
    CFRelease( data );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`, you need  to pass the dictionary saying that your data is a `PICT`.
See the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html). You need to do something like

```
CFDictionaryRef   myOptions = NULL;
CFStringRef       myKeys[1];
CFTypeRef         myValues[1];

myKeys[0] = kCGImageSourceTypeIdentifierHint;
myValues[0] = (CFTypeRef)kUTTypePICT;
myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **) myKeys,
               (const void **) myValues, 1,
               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
               & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

cgImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, myOptions);

CFRelease(myOptions);
```